# Powershell: Compare-Object, Move/Copy-Item with part of subfolders

Tags: powershell

I'm on Windows 10 and Powershell 7.x.

I want to copy/move JPG-files that have a corresponding Nikon-RAW-file (.NEF). If there is a filename with a NEF and a JPG extension, the JPG-file should be copied/moved to a target-folder. But if there is a filename with only a NEF or JPG extension, they should remain untouched.

The images reside in a folder-structure like this:

P:\sources\nikon\yyyy\yyyymmdd\

Every day of shooting has its own subdirectory inside of its entire year-folder.

This code (copy-variant) selects all those files correctly from all subfolders of the year 2011 and copies them to the destination folder (outfile-statement is currently not working):

```
$Folder1 = "P:\sources\nikon\2011"
$Folder2 = "P:\sources\nikon\2011"
$Folder3 = "P:\checkit\temp"
$logfile = $folder3 + "\Log_" + (Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d-%H%M%S").tostring() + ".txt"

$Folder1Contents = Get-childitem $Folder1 -Recurse -Include *.jpg
$Folder2Contents = Get-childitem $Folder2 -Recurse -Include *.nef

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Folder1Contents -DifferenceObject $Folder2Contents -Property basename -PassThru -IncludeEqual | Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq "=="} | Copy-Item -Destination $Folder3 -Recurse -Force | out-file  -append $logfile
```

But this code flattens the directory structure. This is not what I want.

Question:

How do I have to modify the code to copy the selected files including their 2 last subdirectories to get a target-file-structure like this:

P:\checkit\temp\yyyy\yyyymmdd\file(s)

Example:

P:\checkit\temp\2011\20111028\image001.jpg

The out-file-statement currently just creates the log-file but with no content for any reason. It would be nice to write the copied filenames including their subfolder-structure to the log (example: P:\checkit\temp\2011\20111028\image001.jpg).

Thank you for your time.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Try following and then group by filename as needed

```
$RootFolder = 'C:\temp\images'

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolder | Where-Object { ($_.Name -like '*.jpg') -or ($_.Name -like '*.nef')}
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$pattern = '(?<name>[^.]+)\.(?<ext>.*)'
foreach($file in $files)
{
   $file.Name -match $pattern | Out-Null

   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Filename -NotePropertyValue $Matches.name

   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Extension -NotePropertyValue $Matches.ext
   $table.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null
}

$table
```

Results

```
Filename Extension
-------- ---------
image001 jpg
image001 nef
image002 jpg
image004 jpg
image004 nef
image005 jpg
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this does not copy the subfolder-structure. The Compare-Oject result gives me all files that have to be copied/moved. My code does this well by flattening the folder-structure, but I want to copy/move the files AND their last 2 (parent) subfolders, too. Maybe a loop will do the job but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: There are lots of samples.  Do a web search for "stackoverflow.com powershell folder copy move"