# Turn an array into a custom object with headers from $array[0]?

Tags: arrays, powershell, admin, google-workspace, pscustomobject

I'm trying to use GAM to pull chromebook info.
For anyone who knows, GAM is a command-line interface for Google Admin.
The command I'm using specifically is

```
gam print cros limit_to_ou $ou basic
```

It spits out an array, but it does so with the first value being the actual headers.

$array[0] returns

```
deviceId,annotatedAssetId,annotatedLocation,annotatedUser,etc.
```

$array[1] returns

```
dev001,123456,Head Office,john.doe,etc.
```

The problem is, I need to be able to grab specific fields from the rest of the array. I need to pull the annotatedUser, and for logging I want the rest as well. But I need to do this ~9000 times.

Is there an easy way to convert this array to a PSCustomObject that I can use the $array[0] line as the header after a .Split(",")?

Part of me wonders if I don't just output to a CSV and then import it back.

I've been looking around, but this seems to be a very unique issue, and the answers I've seen don't look like they're applicable to my untrained eyes.

Comment: It sounds like you could pipe that directly to `ConvertFrom-Csv`

Comment: You can use Add-Member similar to for loop in my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76128894/powershell-compare-object-move-copy-item-with-part-of-subfolders/76129236#comment134286221_76129236